# Loopback reset the sort order to ASC

Tags: loopback

I am using loopback 3. This is the API call that I am doing to fetch the record in descending order.

```
const orderDetail = await Order.app.models.OrderDetail.findOne(
      {
        where: { orderid: orderId },
        order: 'index DESC',
      }
);
```

But loopback is discarding my sort order and using INDEX default. Below is the sql that I get setting DEBUG strings.

```
SELECT "id","index","timestamp", ............. FROM "public"."orderdetail"  ORDER BY "index" ASC LIMIT 1 +4ms
```

There is no scope defined in model definition.

Answer (score 1):

I remembered that I have had override the find method of model where it had set the defult order. I had done this earlier to prevent default sort (order by id) which was causing database performance issue.

```
const builtInFindMethod = OrderDetail.find;
    OrderDetail.find = function findOrderDetails(filter, ...args) {
const processedFilter = { ...filter, order: 'index ASC' };
      return builtInFindMethod.apply(this, [processedFilter, ...args]);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change the order object, try the below given code :

```
const orderDetail = await Order.app.models.OrderDetail.findOne(
  {
    where: { orderid: orderId },
    order: ['index DESC'],
  });
```

Comment: This is the same query which I am using from past 2 years, may be some other issue is there.

Comment: Yeah. This would totally work if there is no override.